# Area-colored phase diagram for various ranges of f(a,b), given the ranges of a and b

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is there a way to plot a simple diagram in Mathematica with colored areas, like a phase diagram, for the different ranges of values of a function such $f(a,b)=(1-a)/(b+2)$, for various combinations of $a$ & $b$?

I mean, for example, if $0<a<1$ and $0<b<2$, plot a diagram where the x-axis is $a$, and the y-axis is $b$, in which the area where $1/4<f<1/2$ is colored red, and $0<f<1/4$ is colored blue and the rest is white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RegionPlot`(I changed your example a little bit because of `0<f<1/2`)

```
Show[{
RegionPlot[0 < (1 - a)/(2 + b) < 1/4, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},PlotStyle -> Blue],
RegionPlot[1/4 < (1 - a)/(2 + b) < 1/2, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},PlotStyle -> Red]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you! I have edited my question 'for the educational purpose', in-order to fit with your observation about f.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ContourPlot`, specify the desired contours, and also use a non-default `ColorFunction` option. I also needed to use `ColorFunctionScaling` so that function values are left alone.

```
f[a_,b_] := (1-a)/(b+2)

ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},
    Contours->{0, 1/4, 1/2},
    ColorFunction -> Function @ Piecewise[{{Red, 1/4<#<1/2}, {Blue, 0<#<1/4}}, White],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also works well.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[a_, b_] := (1 - a)/(b + 2)
```

You can use a single `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[{0< f[a,b] <= 1/4, 1/4 < f[a,b] <= 1/2}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},
  PlotStyle ->{Blue, Red}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Alternatively, `RegionPlot` with the options  [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html)+[`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html)+ [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
RegionPlot[True, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {f[#, #2] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1/4, 1/2}},
  MeshShading -> {Blue, Red, White}]
```

[image]

`ContourPlot` with the option [`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html):

```
ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 2},
  Contours -> { 1/4, 1/2},
  ContourShading -> {Blue, Red, White}]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, using [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

```
f[a_, b_] = (1 - a)/(2 + b);

boundary = b /. Solve[f[a, b] == 1/4, b][[1]]

(* -2 (-1 + 2 a) *)

Show[
 Plot[boundary, {a, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> {0, 2},
    Frame -> True,
    Filling -> {1 -> #}] & /@
  {{Bottom, Red}, {Top, Blue}},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {a, b})]
```

[image]